# mod_rewrite & .htaccess can't pass variables in OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, osx-yosemite

I have a simple rewrite rule, which works fine as expected:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$  user.php?id=$1
```

I have a php file with:

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

That works fine with the following URL, and id gets passed no problem:

http://localhost/user?id=JoeUser

I know that mod_rewrite is working because this url also sends me to user.php:

http://localhost/user/JoeUser

But JoeUser is never actually passed to $1.  I have never seen this behaviour before.  Is it a bug in OS X, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you edit your http.conf to: AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymlinks
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
        Allow from all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bug in OS X?

No this is not a bug. This is effect of `MultiViews` option which is enabled by default in your Apache config. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

To turn it off use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hot Dawg, you are good!  That works.  It was a frustrating process doing a simple .htaccess tutorial online and then running into a brick wall like this.   The additional benefit of your answer is that I now have other specific aspects of this system that I need to study and bone up on.   Thank you.